# Ionic Framework / Cordova Camera

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic / Cordova Android dev. I've been trying to put in cordova camera plugin for last few days with no outcomes. Please help me out.

What I want to do is when you slide to a certain slide, the camera is loaded and the user is able to take the picture. (Like snapchat)

1. How do I have the camera already loaded? All the examples I saw had to click a button to load camera.
2. If I try the examples, I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

error for this line in `cordova.js`

> var channel = require('cordova/channel');

I'm using $ionicPlatform.ready() function to replace deviceready function. Is this something viable?

I don't really have much of code for this specific problem. But if you want to see it, I will update it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You seems to missing the import for the require lib.

http://requirejs.org/ you can use the CDN //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.11/require.min.js

Just include

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.11/require.min.js"></script>
```

**BEFORE** you import the cordova.js.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing requireJS. Use `npm install -g requirejs` to install it via nodejs

I believe this would be helpful in sorting things out for you.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html

https://github.com/azizimusa/phonegap-demo