# Create Custom Camera view using Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, camera, ionic-framework

I want to create a Photo Capture app using Ionic. I have gone through Cordova Camera Plugin and the examples only shows how to open native camera on button click.

Is there a way to load the Camera view directly in the app (like default camera app, snapchat etc.)? 
I want to open camera inside the app because I want to further add options to the camera, open gallery when user slides the camera etc.

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks

---

The problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298695/ionic-framework-cordova-camera) question but the response does not solve my problem.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Started an ionic project like this...

Comment: like @JimTheDev has mentioned thr is nothing that currently exists and the project i was working on wasn't worth so much tiime investment. Would love to contribute if some is working on it though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to accomplish this with the plugins that currently exist but it might be helpful for you to know what terminology is used when describing this problem. Specifically it sounds like you're wanting to use a custom camera overlay or what is sometimes called a custom camera. You'd likely need to create your own plugin to do what you described but could use something like this as a base: https://github.com/performanceactive/phonegap-custom-camera-plugin

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cordova-plugin-camera-preview](https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview) that allows camera interaction from inside the application.

Comment: does this plugin allows to capture video as well?

Comment: @dzona no it does not