# How to use PlugIns in PhoneGap on MAC OSX? I always mess with "TypeError" & "ReferenceError:"

Tags: android, ios, macos, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am newbie in Phonegap.
I did installed latest version of phoneGap app for MAC OSX.
Below is version detail.[MAC OSX PhoneGap App version detail :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plDnu.png).

I did cerated New PhoneGap project. Now i wants to use [cordova-plugin-qrcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode-reader) in my PhoneGap project.
I am confused it with few days.

I tried many steps for it, But having no success yet :(

I installed below with CLI:

- node -v  --  v6.1.0
- phonegap -v   --   6.2.2
- npm -v   --   3.8.6
- cordova -v   --   6.1.1

I did add `package.json` file in my project directoey.Then i applied `npm install qrcode-reader` command on my Terminal. So `node_modules` folder created in my project directory. [Displaying node_modules hierachy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aehcz.png)

Then i edited my `config.xml` file for add below `PlugIn` tag :

```
<plugin name="qrcode-reader" source="npm" spec="~0.1.1" />
```

Now, In my `index.html` i gave reference for plugin by add below script :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/qrcode-reader/dist/browser.js"></script>
```

Now , In `index.js`, i did use it according to plugin suggest by below code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                  var QrCode = require('qrcode-reader');
                  var qr = new QrCode();
                  qr.callback = function(result) { console.log(result) }
                });
```

But whenever i run this project i got below error :

```
ReferenceError: require is not definedvar
var QrCode = require('qrcode-reader');
```

Though i did search on web till last few days, didn't get any success.
Please help me with this.
Correct me if there any conceptual mistakes.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried running this command `npm run compile-browser`?

Comment: tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298695/ionic-framework-cordova-camera ?

Comment: Hi Shubhank, According to that post i installed [required npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/required)  But still getting same alert.